# How do I stripe table rows with uneven number of rows per stripe with CSS?

Tags: css

I've trying to produce alternate stripes on an HTML table, although the stripes can be many rows high. I'm looking for a way in CSS to use markers to indicate the change in stripes.

Maybe using a CSS equivalent to jQuery's nextUntil()?

I've tried using general sibling selectors but to no avail.

I would like a result that alternated between red and blue backgrounds between the markers.

```css
div {height: 10px; background:yellow}
div.marker:nth-child(2n+1) ~ div {background: red} 
div.marker:nth-child(2n) ~ div {background: blue}
```

```html
<div class="marker"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="marker"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="marker"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="marker"> </div>
<div></div>
<div class="marker"> </div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: If you have the ability to add a “marker” class, any reason you can’t just add a “red” class to some and a “blue” class to others to simplify things? Just making sure you aren’t trying to overthink this. I don’t have an answer to the question you asked, but was hoping maybe you could solve the problem differently.

Comment: @Nate Actually the "stripes" can get sorted (via JavaScript) so that can will jumble around. The colors should still alternate consistently though.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you’re asking for. Any chance you could put together a crude drawing of what you want? Just some rectangles with colors would help.

Comment: The resulting table would **look** something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bcmpu51L/ The colors are still alternating the same way a table is normally striped with the `:nth-child()` selector. Only some "rows" are higher than others.